# At what value should I choose the MOSFET resistors for the MOSFET triggered by the MCU?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver, trigger

I have added a picture of my circuit.

Vcc = 5 V and Rled = appr. 600 Ω.

So, I_Rled_current = 6-7 mA.

The MCU is an ATmega328p.

MCU pd1 and pd2 are logical high and logical low.

What should the values of the R1, R3 and R2, R4 resistors be? Or even, what range should the resistors' values be in?

[image]

Comment: R1 and R3 purpose to protect MCU output. Few hundreds Ohm. R2 and R4 to discharge gate capacitance. Few hundreds kOhm.

Comment: The micro could drive the LED directly, there's no need for the FETs...

Answer (score 3):

R1 and R3 are there only to protect the MCU, because a gate is a little capacitor (a few picofarads), and the resistor will prevent current spikes when charging/discharging it, which could in theory harm MCU. Typical values are 100, 120, 240 Ohm, usually not more than that. In fact, often you can omit them, especially for prototype or personal device, but it's considered a good practice to include them. Just put them there and sleep safely.

The R2 and R4 are pulldown resistors that explicitly define default pin state so that while MCU isn't outputting anything (such as during power up and before MCU gate pins are explicitly set), the gate will have a fixed voltage value and not float around picking up random stuff from the environment. Typical values would be 10k (most no-brainer default), but can be 4.7k or 20k. Even 100k could work, but it's better not to go too high.

R1+R2 and R3+R4 make voltage dividers, so they should differ by orders of magnitude, so that you have full voltage swing on the MOSFET gate (for example, if R1 = R2, then when you make that pin HIGH, you will have not 5V but 2.5V on the gate, and the whole thing probably won't work as you want).

So, typical no-brainer combination is 100R+10k. You can deviate from it if you have other parts at hand. As long as you understand what you do and why.

Comment: Putting R2/R4 before R1/R3 would "remove" voltage divider from the gate. It's usually more viable configuration when MOSFET are driven directly from the MCU.

Comment: @Ilya Could the R2 resistor be 1k?Is there any problem with this situation?

Comment: @mike_lay944 it's all relative. In fact, I'd go with NStorm advice and put the pull-down before the gate resistor (on MCU side of the gate resistor). That way, yes, it can be 1k without any problem. It's just that when you have that line HIGH, you will have 5mA flowing through it, effectively a waste. If you don't care about it, there is no other reason not to do that. If you have pull-down at the gate, then you will have a voltage divider at the gate, and the gate top voltage will be limited by voltage divider output (gate resistor + pull-down; Can be 4.7V or even 4.5V instead of 5V).

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need any series resistors. The 2N7002's input capacitance is at most 50pF, which the Mega328P's outputs are specified to drive just fine. In other words, you can choose R1 = R3 = 0 Ohms.

To keep the FETs off when the microcontroller is not driving them, you could choose R2 = R4 = 100kOhms or so. The value really isn't critical. Your controller can drive 20mA on each output, so the pulldown resistors should consume at least an order of magnitude less current than that. Of course, if you make them too big (tens of Megaohms), any contamination on the PCB may influence the FET's gate when the controller is off.